# Minikube with nginx ingress path rewrite issue

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm using minikube with nginx ingress.

I'm trying to use url rewriting like [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/)

Here is my ingress definition:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: config-reader-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: default-http-backend
    servicePort: 80
  rules:
  - host: microservices.info
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /reload(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: spring-cloud-reload
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /upload(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: spring-cloud-upload
          servicePort: 8080
```

The following urls rewrites like this:

- `/reload`   to `/`
- `/reload/xyx` to `/xyz`

which is fine. But

- `/reload/x/y` rewrites to `/x//` instead of `/x/y`

also

- `/reload/x/y/` rewrites to `/x/y//` instead of `/x/y/`

> minikube version: v0.35.0

**How can be fixed the multiple path elements case?**

**UPDATE**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:    0.21.0
  Build:      git-b65b85cd9
  Repository: https://github.com/aledbf/ingress-nginx
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What version of nginx-ingress controller do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior nginx-ingress v0.22.0 there was a known issue with trailing slashes.

To detect which version of the ingress controller is running, exec into the pod and run nginx-ingress-controller version command.

```
kubectl exec -it $POD_NAME -- /nginx-ingress-controller --version

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:    0.24.1
  Build:      git-ce418168f
  Repository: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Rewrite target annotation is very sensitive for trailing slashes. If it's not present, the request will not be rewritten.

Thus, you should always supply  url as `/reload/x/y/`

Another problem with duplicated trailing slashes (fixed in v 0.22.0 and higher).

In order to understand, what's is going on there, you can exec to ingress-controller pod, find `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and search for

```
set $location_path  "/reload(/|${literal_dollar})(.*)";
```

or

```
rewrite "(?i)/reload(/|$)(.*)" /$2 break;
```

blocks

To fix it, either update ingress-controller version to the latest or you can also use [configuration-snippet](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#configuration-snippet) annotation:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
    rewrite (?i)/reload/x/y/ /x/y break;
```